# Incorporating Bootstrap Form Helpers into simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I am trying to implement a select menu with **countries**, which then filters a select menu with **states** once a country is selected.

I use SimpleForm and Bootstrap so the following seems to suit me perfectly: http://vincentlamanna.com/BootstrapFormHelpers/state.html

I currently use the country_select gem with SimpleForm and my code contains:

```
<%= f.input :country, :id => "business_country", :input_html => { :class => "span6" } %>
<%= f.input :state, :input_html => { :class => "span6" } %>
```

When I included the relevant js files and include the default sample code for Bootstrap Form Helpers the behaviour works as expected but I would like to include it in my SimpleForm so I can save to the database. Here is the default example code that performs correctly:

```
<select id="countries_states1" class="input-medium bfh-countries" data-country="US"></select>
<select class="input-medium bfh-states" data-country="countries_states1"></select>
```

Could anyone suggest how to implement this is SimpleForm?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by finding the correct id of my country select (business_country as seen in my code in my original question) and adding the data-country to the input_html in SimpleForm for the state select. The code:

```
<%= f.input :country, :input_html => { :class => "span6 input-medium bfh-countries"} %>
<%= f.input :state, as: :select, :input_html => {:class => "span6 input-medium bfh-states", 'data-country' => ('business_country') } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions on the `simple_form` gem readme to install with Bootstrap support? https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#twitter-bootstrap

`rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forgot to mention that. I believe my main problem is how to incorporate the `data-country="countries_states1"` into my simpleform field. Perhaps something like `:input_html => {"data-remote" => true` but I'm not quite sure what to use.